Type hints for a function (multiprocessing)
The following function creates an instance of a class that can be shared between processes:
def create_shared_object (constructor: ?) -> ?:

    from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager;

    BaseManager.register('name', constructor);

    manager = BaseManager();

    manager.start();

    return manager.name();

What are the correct type hints?

This is a seriously problematic function - you're creating a new server process on every single call to this function, as well as reusing the single typeid name for every type you register.

Function works as intended: it creates an instance of a class that can be accessed by several processes.
As for it being problematic because it reuses the same typeid, you are right. I, however, didn't run into any problems with it, because I use it only once. I moved it into a separate function to make code more readable.

This question is similar to: How can I specify the function type in my type hints?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I want to know which type hints I should use in this particular case. The argument is a class and return value is an instance of that class created using BaseManager.

I guess Callable is the correct type for the argument, but I'm not sure as it's not just a function, it's a class. As for return value I just don't know. I could not find which type hint to use for an instance of an unspecified class, especially one that was constructed via BaseManager.

Such generated methods of a manager returns an instance of the BaseProxy type.
Depending on the argument to proxytype, the type might change:
def create_shared_object(...):
    BaseManager.register(..., proxytype = CustomProxy)
    ...

class C: ...

t = type(create_shared_object(C))
print(t)  # CustomProxy

When proxytype is not given or None, an AutoProxy class is dynamicaly generated. It is not importable and cannot be used as a type hint (in which case, use BaseProxy).
def create_shared_object(...):
    BaseManager.register(..., proxytype = None)

...

# multiprocessing.managers.AutoProxy[name]
print(t)

# (AutoProxy[name], BaseProxy, object)
print(t.__mro__)

As for constructor, the type BaseManager.register expects is Callable[..., object] | None. Classes are also callable, so it is fine to use this type even if you intend to pass a class.
# From typeshed
class BaseManager:
    ...
    @classmethod
    def register(
        cls,
        typeid: str,
        callable: Callable[..., object] | None = None,
        #         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        proxytype: Any = None,
        exposed: Sequence[str] | None = None,
        method_to_typeid: Mapping[str, str] | None = None,
        create_method: bool = True,
    ) -> None: ...

